# Django template changes width of html element during append

Tags: jquery, css, django, django-templates, width

I have noticed that when I port my html code into Django template the width of the html element changes a bit. Here is what is happening (see the HTML code below):

1. I define jQuery object an give it css attribute width = 498px.
2. I immediately print out (using JS alert command) the width attribute and it is still 498px as expected.
3. I append the object to the $("body")
4. I print out object's css width attribute again, and it is changed to 497.7665px.

So it looks like the problem occurs during appending the object to "body".

Exactly same code does not have that problem when I am just loading it from file without Django template.

Why is this happening and is there any way around it?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Finally I was able to isolate the problem. Below is the HTML code. Like I said, if you try to load it into the browser directly, both alerts (before placement onto "body" and after) will give you width=498px as expected.

However, if you set it up as Django template and run with Django development server, the second alert (after placement onto "body") will give you a slightly different number depending on the browser:
Firefox gives 497.76666px,
IE gives 498.1px.
I have not checked other browsers.

It is important to note, that it is that combination of css attributes ("left", "top", "width", "height", "border-width", "background-color", "border-style") that shows the problem. If you remove at least one of them, the problem goes away.

If you happen know what is going on and/or what the viable workaround is, I would really appreciate it. Thanks. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var my_element = $("<div/>")
                             .addClass("my_element")
                             .attr("id", "my_element1")
                             .css("position", "absolute")
                             .css("left", "0px")
                             .css("top", "0px")
                             .css("width", "498px")
                             .css("height", "300px")            
                             .css("border-width", "1px")
                             .css("background-color", "#999966")
                             .css("border-style", "solid");

            alert("width:" + my_element.css("width"));  

            $("body").append(my_element);

            alert("width:" + my_element.css("width"));  

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough to go on, as you didn't give us any code. Django doesn't change the HTML in the templates it renders without explicitly written logic. I would suggest taking your original HTML and use that as the template without replacing anything (no template tags, etc) and see if the page layout is what you expect. Then you can add the template tags, etc, back one by one and refresh after adding each item back. Once the layout messes up again, you'll know what caused the issue and can fix it.

Comment: Thanks, a good idea. I did try to use my original html as template without any template tags and also added some debug printouts (I updated my question with more info). I still see the problem using Django: it is when the element is appended to "body",the width gets corrupted. If you have any clue, let me know.

Comment: Steps 1 through 4 listed above all occur client side, no Django involved. Is this jQuery running in the original HTML? I think we'd need to see the code behind Step #1 (how the object is defined and width set).

Comment: Thanks again for your input. Anyway, I was able to isolate the issue. I added EDIT section of the question and put the HTML code there. I would really appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I still don't understand how you resolved it.